# Is there any way to parse a btsnoop log capture file and extract data from it by filtering using python or any other way?

Tags: parsing, logging, bluetooth, hci, btsnoop

I wanted to parse a btsnoop log file and extract the l2cap data from it Is there any way to parse a btsnoop log capture file and extract data from it by filtering using python or any other way?. I am able to convert the .cfa file into a txt file which contains hex data. I am getting extra data with the raw data.I am able to convert the .cfa file into a txt file which contains hex data.

I am able to convert the .cfa file into a txt file which contains hex data.

Comment: Wireshark (and so tshark) will parse btsnoop. https://wiki.wireshark.org/FileFormatReference

Comment: But actually I want to automate the process with some python script, is it possible anway?

Comment: Yes, python can call tshark, which will output text, which python can parse. You can also search for python-native btsnoop parsers. https://github.com/traviswpeters/btsnoop https://pypi.org/project/btsnoop/